# Array of size n to array n x 2 using Java 8 stream

Tags: arrays, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to figure out the most elegant way of converting a simple `int` array (e.g. `{1, 2, 3}`) to a simple `String` array (e.g. `{"id", "1", "id", "2", "id", "3"}`) of String pairs using Java 8 streams.

Traditionally the code looks like this: -

```
int[] input = {1, 2, 3};

String[] output = new String[input.length * 2];

int i = 0;
for (int val : input) {
    output[i++] = "id";
    output[i++] = String.valueOf(val);
}
```

But assuming this can be done in a 1-liner in Java 8.

Comment: It can't be done in a one-liner (unless the line contains several chained instructions), and the for loop is faster, and simpler to read and understand anyway. I would rather wonce why you would need an array where every even element has the same value. It's redundant, and thus a sign of a design smell.

Comment: To me, the most reasonable way to implement it: either: for (int i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {
            output[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? "id" : String.valueOf(input[i / 2]);
        }, OR: IntStream.range(0, output.length).forEach(i -> output[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? "id" : String.valueOf(input[i / 2]));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(input)
            .mapToObj(x -> new String[] { "id", "" + x })
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Or may be a bit more verbose (but worse since we are first joining, only to split immediately after)

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(input)
            .mapToObj(x -> "id" + "," + x)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
            .split(",");
```

I can think of these two, but it's hardly more readable of what you already have in place with a simple for loop.

Comment: `.mapToObj` didn't work here, `map` seemed OK though?

Comment: @bobmarksie if your input is really `int[] input = { 1, 2, 3 };` than `mapToObj` and not `map`. If you say `map` works it means your input contains Objects (`Integer`) and not primitives

Comment: Hey, you can transform `int` to `String` first, e.g:`mapToObj(String::valueOf).flatMap(it-> Stream.of("id", it))...`

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I'm a bit proponent of readability vs new-shiny-way-of-doing-things and it seems in this instance it isn't more readable.

Comment: IMMHO, this solution is bad, really bad because you either create the totally unnecessary string[] or join/split. Not big deal? Remember the famous code: String str = new String("abc"); It shows your characters in writing codes.

Comment: @123-xyz you are absolutely right; this was not about wrong or right, but just a `java-8` way of doing it. And yes, I would never suggest it in real code

Answer (score 2):

Can make it even less readable than [Eugene's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693997/7598776):

```
String[] output = IntStream.range(0, input.length * 2)
        .mapToObj(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? "id" : input[x / 2 ] + "")
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

And another variation of this can be next:

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream( input )
                .boxed()
                .flatMap( x -> Stream.of( "id", Integer.toString( x ) ) )
                .toArray( String[]::new );
```